# Why am I getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined' (react-router, React-Redux)?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-router, reactjs

I first started working on this with the following, 'HomePage.js' as the only smart component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import actions from '../redux/actions'

import AppFloatBar from './AppFloatBar'
import MainCoverPhoto from './MainCoverPhoto'
import FirstPage from '../pages/FirstPage'

import { deepOrange500, grey400 } from 'material-ui/styles/colors'

import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import darkBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/darkBaseTheme'


const muiTheme = getMuiTheme(
  darkBaseTheme,
  {
    palette: {
      accent1Color: deepOrange500,
      textColor: grey400,
      textColor2: grey400,
    },
    appBar:{
      height: 67,
      color:'black',
      textColor:'#A0A0A0',
    },
  }
);

class HomePage extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <div>
          <AppFloatBar
            actions={this.props.actions}
            floatBar={this.props.floatBar}
          />
          <MainCoverPhoto/>
          <div className="thread_body">
            {(() => {
              switch (this.props.children.props.route.path) {
                case 'Page 1':
                  return <FirstPage addTodo={this.props.actions.addTodo}    actions={this.props.actions}
                  todos={this.props.todos}
                  inputTexts={this.props.inputTexts}
                  />
                case 'Page 2':
                  return this.props.children
                case 'Page 3':
                  return this.props.children
                default:
                  return this.props.children
              }
            })()}
          </div>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return state
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(HomePage)
```

With the following react-router, in client.js:

```
render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route
          path="/"
          component={HomePage}
        >
            <IndexRoute
              component={MainCard}
            />
            <Route
              component={FirstPage}
              path="Page 1"
            />
            <Route
              component={SecondPage}
              path="Page 2"
            />
            <Route
              component={ThirdPage}
              path="Page 3"
            />
            <Route
              component={ThreadPage}
              path="/discussion/:id"
            />
            <Route
              component={StaticPage}
              path="Static"
            />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

And it worked fine. But I decided to make a 'MainPage' which is what I would like the website to start off with now. I would like to start off with 'MainPage' and when a button is clicked on, go to the 'HomePage' So I revised the react-router in client.js:

```
render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route
          component={MainPage}
          path="/"
        />
        <Route
          component={HomePage}
          path="Home"
        />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

With the following in 'MainPage.js':

```
render(){
    return(
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <div>
            <RaisedButton
              containerElement={<Link to={`Home`}/>}
              label="Sign In"
              labelColor='#88898C'
              labelStyle={{textTransform:'intial'}}
              style={styles.signIn}
            />
    </div>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        )
      }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return state
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
      }
    }

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
    )(MainPage)
```

Now when the button in 'MainPage.js' is clicked on, the link/URL changes to 'Home' correctly, but shows up the following error message for 'HomePage.js':

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

Trying to resolve it but seem to continue to overlook the issue. What may be the issue? Any help would be greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that in your first implementation, `HomePage` is a container component. `HomePage` is always rendered and inside of it other components are rendered.

In your follow-up, `HomePage` is no longer a container component. No other components are rendered inside of it. This means that `this.props.children` is `undefined` (it probably should be an empty array, but that's a React design decision).

In the `switch` condition, since `this.props.children` is `undefined`, doing `undefined.props.route.path` throws that `TypeError`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! If I want to make the 'HomePage' as container, but 'MainPage.js' still as the front page but not render any other components inside it, how should I go about doing so?

Comment: You have to define at least an `IndexRoute` inside of the `HomePage` route.

Comment: If this answer fixed your problem, please consider accepting it. Thanks! http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png